# How to set multiple `orderby` in query argument?

Tags: wp-query, order, menu-order

I am trying to fetch pages by multiple ordering. `menu_order` in descending and `title` in ascending.
Following is the argument:

```
$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'page',
 'posts_per_page' => 20,
 'orderby' => array( 'menu_order' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC' ),
 );
```

But it is not ordering as I expecting and gives following warning.

`Warning: urldecode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/staging.dev/public_html/wp-includes/query.php on line 2634`

I found a ticket in trac regarding multiple `orderby`. I studied the discussion and followed as in the discussion but could not solve the issue.
[Ticket Link](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17065)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced ordering feature is now added in the new version of WordPress. I came to know this after release of WordPress 4.0.

Check [this announcement](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/) for more detail.

**Example:**

```
$q = new WP_Query( array( 'orderby' => array( 'title' => 'DESC', 'menu_order' => 'ASC' ) ) );
```